# How to broadcast higher dimensional arrays into smaller dimension array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I wish to broadcast different shape arrays, into the same array.

Lets say I have two inputs, and 10 points. `input1` is a scalar, `input2` is a 3 by 3 tensor. I want both to live in the `input_array`.

```
import numpy as np

input_array = np.zeros((10,2))
input1 = np.random.rand(10)      # scalar
input2 = np.random.rand(3,3,10)  # 3x3 tensor
```

I want to do this:

```
input_array[:,0] = input1  # this works 
input_array[:,1] = input2  # this doesn't because input2's dimension is different
```

I have tried moving around the axes of `input2`, also I've tried it with pandas.DataFrame. I think you could do this when converting the 3*3 tensor to a list, however that results in unwanted behavior downstream. Lastly I could flatten the tensors, but I'm not keen to do that.

Summarizing, there are possibly some ways to get around this, but can it be done?

Comment: You will need to set the shape of ```input_array``` to ```(3,3,10,2)``` and then do ```input_array[...,0] = input1``` and ```input_array[...,1] = input2 ```

Comment: The first 3 dimensions for ```input_array``` will be broadcasted when setting ```input1```.

Comment: Thank you! So that is essentially making the scalar a 3*3 tensor as well... Is it simply impossible to have an array like object with different dimensions in different columns?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **columns**, but the size of the trailing axes must be equal or 1. So comparing the shape ```(10,2)``` with ```(3,3,10)``` they are not eligible for broadcasting.

Comment: I think this article explains the concept very well: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy

Comment: It might be to indirectly broadcast the shape ```(10,2)``` with ```(3,3,10)```. You could reshape ```(10,2)``` to ```(1,1,10,2)``` and then select an index on the last dimension which you are doing ```input_array[:,0]```. You will then have the shape ```(1,1,10,1)``` which can be broadcasted with ```(3,3,10)``` **if** you also reshape ```(3,3,10)``` to ```(3,3,10,1)```.

Comment: ```input2``` can also be broadcasted with the same intuition by reshaping it to ```(1,1,10,1)```

Comment: Ok, just tested it myself. You need the shape of ```input_array``` equal to ```(3,3,10,2)``` in order to match the 3x3 tensor.

Comment: Your `input_array` is float dtype.  Each element is then a number.  Look at `input_array[...,0].shape`.  The RHS has to match.  The array holds numbers, not python objects.  What's wrong with the list approach?

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Exactly, I need input array to be `(3,3,10,2)` to be able to take the tensor. However if then you say `input_array[:,:,:,1] = input2`, and retrieve `input2` by `input_array[:,:,:,1]` the shape of that is now `(3,3,10,)`. Not sure how that performs speed and memory wise.

Comment: Paul, I have had some issues using lists in numpy operations. However I will run some tests to see what will be faster: 1. Using them as lists (given that numpy allows the required operations). 2. broadcast the scalar to a 3*3 tensor as what happens in Kevins approach. 3. flatten the tensor to a long vector, and broadcast the scalar accordingly. Will let you know how that went!

Comment: What I'm wondering is why put `input1` and `input2` in the same arrayat all?  What's the advantage to accessing them with `input_array[:,0]`.  Why not `alist=[input1, input2]`, and access with `alist[0]`?  The list preserves the original dimensions.  WIth the (3,3,10,2) array, you've replicated the (10,) array 9x!

Comment: You can add them, `input1+input2` or `alist[0]+alist[1]`, by the rules of broadcasting.  Kevin's `arr.sum(-1)` would do the same thing, but I don't think it would be any faster.